# Question about Javascript (Jquery) and GET

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get

After getting a new page with $.get none of the javascript will run on the new page.

Is there a way to make javascript use the new page too?

Many thanks

- Dorjan

Edit: Example:

```
$(function() {
    $('.viewPage').click(function() {
        $('#mainarticle').fadeOut('slow')
        $.get($(this).attr('href'), { js: "1" }, function(data) {
            $('#mainarticle').html(data).fadeIn('slow');
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Now this works fine however, the new page's anchor tags won't trigger (lets say it has a .viewPage).

I hope that clarify's the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind events to your anchors using [live](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live):

```
$('a.something').live("click",function() {
    alert('this will still work after a.something has been replaced via ajax');
});
```

Another way using $.get's callback:

```
$.get( "page.html", function(data) {
    $('#someDiv').html(data);
    $('a.something').click(function() {
        alert('this will still work after a.something has been replaced via ajax');
    });
});
```

Now that I've seen your code:

```
$(function() { 
    $('.viewPage').live("click",(function() { 
        $('#mainarticle').fadeOut('slow') 
        $.get($(this).attr('href'), { js: "1" }, function(data) { 
            $('#mainarticle').html(data).fadeIn('slow');
        }); 
        return false; 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Perfect! I had to upgrade my jQuery (I was using 1.2.2 which is why I didn't find this!)

Fantasy, thanks Karim.

Comment: I actually did it before I saw your update (since I had to download the new jQuery, your first instructions was perfect my friend :) )

Comment: (I would've given you a vote up but I can't yet, too new it tells me!)

Comment: @Dorjan - oops, I should have mentioned that you need jQuery 1.3

Answer (score 0):

Yep; there is another jquery ajax method that will take the returned script from your page and execute it. Check the jquery docs.

Comment: Hmm... I'll have a look. Just to make sure we're on the same page the jQuery waits on an anchor tag click. But on the new version of the same page (lets say a ajax reload) all the anchors are ignored.

I've been unsuccessful finding the right function but am reading between checking here.

Comment: I just found jQuery.getScript( url, [callback] ) which I think is what you meant, but wasn't what I meant. I'll clarfy the question.

Thanks though!